# Change background color upon textbox value changed

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to change the background color of my webpage when a color is selected from a *ASPColorPicker* and color code is in textbox. I have this *jQuery* code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor() {
        $('#page').css('background', $("#colorPickerTextBox").val());
    }

    $("#colorPickerTextBox").change(changeColor);
</script>
```

And the *TextBox*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="colorPickerTextBox" onchange="changeColor" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:ColorPickerExtender TargetControlID="colorPickerTextBox" ID="ColorPicker" runat="server">
</asp:ColorPickerExtender>
```

And in *CSS* I have this ID

```
#page {
  width: 990px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 5px;
  background: #FF99FF;
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What errors do you get? What happens?

Comment: I'm confused as to what your issue is, what were you expecting to see happen, what is happening instead?

Comment: Color does not change... This is the error

Comment: Well, what does $("#colorPickerTextBox").val() outputs when you log it? Does the function gets executed?

Comment: @EmeryFramboise I checked by doing this now
 $("#colorPickerTextBox").change(function () {
  $('#page').css('background', '#FFFFF');
  });

This did not work

Comment: Does the change function gets called? What if you console.log something in that function.

Comment: @EmeryFramboise
  $("#colorPickerTextBox").change(function () {
            alert("HElllllo");
        });

Does not alerts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/12/ajax-colorpickerextender.html).

Add a JavaScript function:

```
function selectedColorChanged(sender) {  
    $("#page").css({
        backgroundColor: "#" + sender.get_selectedColor()
    }); 
}
```

And an `OnClientColorSelectionChanged` parameter with this function name to your `ColorPickerExtender`:

```
<asp:ColorPickerExtender TargetControlID="colorPickerTextBox"
    ID="ColorPicker"
    runat="server"
    OnClientColorSelectionChanged="selectedColorChanged">
</asp:ColorPickerExtender>
```

Comment: You are welcome (but please, avoid such comments :))